# Connect a Sitecom WL-174 to another wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I used to connect via a Sitecom WL-174 directly to ADSL internet. There were some pc's which connected wirelessly and some connected with a wire.

Now we got another provider and we need to use the router which came with it. It is also a wireless router. It works perfectly.

But I need to connect the other pc's which were connected with a wire previously.

Is it possible to connect the Sitecom router wirelessly to the other router?

If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: How we doing on this one, chief?

Comment: Thijs. How do you pronounce **Thijs**?  `/THICHZ/`?  I would have trouble saying that quickly. Thijs.  Perhaps you could use a vowel in there.  I recommend an `u` between the `j` and the `s`.  Thijus.  I will now call you Thijus.

Comment: A question was posted by Wouters,

Comment: Regarding his trouble with routers.

Comment: We thought, "With our brains,"

Comment: "We could fix his pains!"

Comment: But his silence has left us all doubters.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make a wireless bridge?

```
                                      |       |
  +----------+    +--------------+   ||       ||   +----------------+
  | Internet |----| New Wireless |--|||       |||--| Sitecom WL-174 |
  |          |    | Router       |   ||       ||   +----------------+
  +----------+    +--------------+    |       |          |
                                                         |
                                                    Wired Computers
```

You'll need a router that supports this specifically.  I didn't see anything in the [manual](http://www.sitecom.com/showdownload.php?id=3130) about wireless bridging.  It did mention "bridge mode" but that refers to a connection to the ISP that is more transparent than the normal settings.

3rd party firmwares like DD-WRT can enable this function but your router is not supported by that.  You could still use it as a switch if you had a really long CAT 5 cable.